# How to use modal in Codeigniter, with separate data and certain id?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a view page (ikhtisar_view). And when I click one ID, it show modal (link to ikhtisar/detail) contain data for that ID only.

Here's my ikhtisar view td (contain data which I can click for detail):

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ikhtisar/detail" class='iframe'><?php echo $ikh['id']?></a></td>
```

This is my controller function:

```
 public function detail()
 {
    $this->load->model('ikhtisar_model');
    $detailr = $this->ikhtisar_model->trx();
    $data['detail'] = $detailr;
    $this->load->view('ikhtisar/trx_view',$data);
 }
```

And this is my model function:

```
 public function trx()
 {  
    $ikh = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->db->select('t.id_transaksi AS id, t.tgl_transaksi AS tgl, t.id_member AS memberid, t.nama AS nama, p.kode_produk AS kode, tp.hp_tujuan AS nohp, d.nama AS nama2, t.saldo_awal AS saw, tp.hpp AS hpp, t.saldo_akhir AS sak, tp.laba AS laba, t.ket AS ket, sr.ket AS ket2, sr.jenis AS sj', FALSE)
->from('transaksi_pulsa tp')
->join('transaksi t','tp.id_transaksi=t.id_transaksi', 'left')
->join('produk p','tp.kode_produk = p.kode_produk', 'left')
->join('set_report sr','t.status=sr.jenis', 'left')
->join('distributor d','tp.id_distributor=d.id_distributor and tp.com=d.com', 'left')
->where('t.id_transaksi', $ikh);

$ikhtisar = $this->db->get();

    return $ikhtisar;       
 }
```

And finally this is my trx_view.php:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table table-bordered" id="ikhtisar">
        <thead style="display: table-header-group; vertical-align: middle; border-color: inherit;">
        <tr>
            <th>Status</th> 
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Tanggal</th>
            <th>Kode RS</th>
            <th>Nama RS</th>
            <th>Produk</th>
            <th>Tujuan</th>
            <th>Stok</th>
            <th>Harga</th>
            <th>Saldo Akhir</th>
            <th>Laba</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <?php foreach($ikhlist->result_array() as $ikh): ?>

          <tr>
            <!--<td><a href="http://localhost/modal/modal.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo $ikh['id']?></a></td>-->
            <td style="font-size: 15px;" align="center"><?php if($ikh['sj'] == '1'){?><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green"></i></span><?php }elseif($ikh['sj'] == '2'){ ?><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red"><?php }else{ ?><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign yellow"><?php }?></i></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $ikh['id']?></td>                                
            <td><?php echo $ikh['tgl']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ikh['memberid']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ikh['nama']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ikh['kode']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ikh['nohp']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ikh['nama2']?></td>
            <td class="text-right"><?php echo number_format($ikh['hpp'], 0, ",", ".")?></td>
            <td class="text-right"><?php echo number_format($ikh['sak'], 0, ",", ".")?></td>

            <td><?php echo $ikh['laba']?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But I got just a page (trx_view.php) with no data. It contain only header. So, how to show the correct data? In ikhtisar_view (before click id for detail), no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your code on your own, 
try to print the query from the model, by using

```
echo $this->db->last->query()
```

Try to run that query on the above received query database, and check whether you are getting the data or not.

And then try to print the `$detail` variable in the view and check whether your view is actually getting the data or not.

Comment: WHERE `t`.`id_transaksi` =  0


So, the problem is in my model function, $ikh is not right, there is no data. Any ideas?

Comment: do this echo $this->db->last->query() in your model function after $ikhtisar = $this->db->get(); ,,,,, it will print the db query, run it on the database. and correct the query accordingly.

Comment: Yes, Nishant, I already do that, and last query is execute model script function trx() above. But, $ikh (this mean id that I clicked) = 0. 
I think: $ikh = $this->input->post('id'); not correct. But I still don't know what the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If I use this  in my ikhtisar_view:

```
<td>
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ikhtisar/detail">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" 
    value="<?php echo $ikh['id']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $ikh['id']; ?>" />
</form> 
</td>
```

Instead of:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ikhtisar/detail" class='iframe' name="id">
<input name="id" value="<?php echo $ikh['id']; ?>" />

</a></td>
```

The form-method succeed with exactly data I clicked (id). But, this is not modal. How to convert it to modal? 
I already try add class='iframe' to that method, it didn't worked. Modal show up, but blank, no data, no header, no footer.